# specifying the correct class to add class Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I attempting to create a flip transition which can been seen [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/7owwvecd/12/) i want this function to activate when the user click on the info button, however i can not seem to target the `.card` class in order to activate the flip transition.

below is a snippet of my jquery

```
 $('.active-btn').click(function(){
            $(this).closest('.card').find('.flip')
            .addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('flipped');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The html would help, maybe the problem is about the dom.

Comment: Your fiddle is broken: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7owwvecd/16/)***
Removing `.find('.flip')` should help, cause you're interested in flipping the `.card`

```
$(this).closest('.card').addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

.find('.flip') will look for element with find class inside .card element, which is not the case per your HTML. As suggested by @Roko : it would help if you remove the .find('.flip') from your script. Also, I see that you have not handled the transform property in css for all the browser, it would be better if you address all the browsers for transform,

```
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
-moz-transform:    rotateY(-180deg);
-ms-transform:     rotateY(-180deg);
-o-transform:      rotateY(-180deg);
transform:         rotateY(-180deg);
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using closest, and find for the .card class, just use the .card class as the selector.

$('.card').addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function()

You'll select any element with .card class, and add the class flipped.